# Отслеживание изменений в m2m поле модели

Tags: python, django

Имеется тип, имеется категория, сущности относятся друг к другу как м2м. Категории имеют иерархию, реализованную через *mptt*.

Требуется при добавлении через админку связи тип-категория добавить к данному типу связь со всеми дочерними категориями данной.

Нашёл в интернете совет явно указать таблицу связи посредством *through*, и в метод *save* данной таблицы добавить свою логику, но этот метод не вызывается. В чём причина - я не знаю.

Код:

```
class AdType(models.Model):
    """
    Класс для типов
    """
    name = models.CharField(_(u'Название'), max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(_(u'Слаг'), max_length=50, unique=True, help_text=_(u'Наименование в URL'))
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(_(u'Дата создания'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(_(u'Дата обновления'), auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_(u'Включён'))
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField(_(u'Позиция'), default=1, help_text=_(u'Влияет на порядок отображения списка типов'))
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, verbose_name=_(u'Сайты'), help_text=_(u'Отображать тип на следующих сайтах'))
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name=_(u'Категории'), help_text=_(u'Категории для данного типа объявлений'), related_name='types', through='AdTypeToCategories')

    objects = BatchManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']
        verbose_name = _(u'тип')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'Типы')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class AdTypeToCategories(models.Model):
    ad_type = models.ForeignKey(AdType)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.add_category()
        super(AdTypeToCategories, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def add_category(self):
        """
        При выборе категорий выбирает и все дочерние категории
        При снятие категории, снимает и со всех дочерних
        """

        # Если это новая категория
        if not self.pk:
            # То добавим все её дочерние категории
            child_categories = self.category.get_children()
            self.ad_type.categories.add(child_categories)
            self.ad_type.save()


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'catalog_adtype_categories'
        auto_created = AdType
```

Есть идеи как решить задачу? И почему метод *save AdTypeToCategories* не вызывается?

Помню, в *Django* есть оптимизация для массового редактирования, вот на неё я и попал, а как её явно обойти - не помню.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих поисков наконец решил свою задачу!

для отслеживания изменения в m2m полях в Django предусмотрен сигнал m2m_changed: http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/signals.html#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed
Я реализовал его приёмник и сделал добавление дочерних категорий.

С удалением всё несколько сложнее. Дело в том, что сигнал с описанным в документации действием pre_remove не приходит (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16073) Дело в том, что django работает несколько иначе, чем написано в документации - в действительности никакого удаления не происходит, просто в методе clear очищается старый список связей и в методе add формируется новый, поэтому мне приходится брать старый список значений до очистки в действие pre_clear и в действие pre_add сверять с новым, выявляя удалённые. Далее представляю полный код моего алгоритма обработки сигнала m2m_changed для представленных выше в вопросе моделей:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=AdType.categories.through)
def ad_type_categories_changed(sender, instance, action, reverse, pk_set, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Алгоритм для добавления дочерних категорий:
    1) Получаем список всех новых категорий через список их primary_key (pk_set)
    2) Для каждой из категорий, посредством метода django_mmpt get_descendants получаем всех потомков объединяя их всех в единый список child_categories
    3) Формируем new_pk_set из списка child_categories
    4) Добавляем в pk_set все значения из new_pk_set

    Алгоритм удаления дочерних категорий:
    1) В действие pre_clear получаем старый список связанных категорий, сохраняем его в instanse
    2) Собираем список кетегорий, которые были удалены
    3) Собираем список всех дочерних категорий, для списка удалённых категорий
    4) # Исключаем дочерние категории удалённых из списка новых категорий (pk_set)

    Сложность данного алгоритма в том, что django не удаляет связанные объекты, поэтому нельзя просто обратиться к действию pre_remove, описанному в документации,
    вместо этого каждый раз при сохранение связанных, django пересоздаёт список связанных объектов
    """

    if action == 'pre_add' and not reverse:

        # Добавляем связь с типом всем дочерним категориям при добавление данной
        categories = Category.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_set)
        child_categories = []
        for category in categories:
            child_categories.extend(category.get_descendants())
        new_pk_set = []
        for category in child_categories:
            new_pk_set.append(category.pk)

        pk_set.update(new_pk_set)

        # Собираем список кетегорий, которые были удалены
        removed_categories = [] # cписок удалённых категорий
        for category in instance.old_categories:
            if category.pk not in pk_set:
                removed_categories.append(category)

        # Собираем список всех дочерних категорий, для списка удалённых категорий
        child_categories = []
        for category in removed_categories:
            child_categories.extend(category.get_descendants())
        new_pk_set = []
        for category in child_categories:
            new_pk_set.append(category.pk)

        # Исключаем дочерние категории удалённых из списка новых категорий
        for pk in new_pk_set:
            if pk in pk_set:
                pk_set.remove(pk)

    # Собираем старый набор категорий
    if action == 'pre_clear':
        instance.old_categories = list(instance.categories.all())


m2m_changed.connect(ad_type_categories_changed, sender=AdType.categories.through)
```